# Simple database in C using a binary search tree

Tags: c, database, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I was tasked with writing a simple database in C. The program would receive instructions in stdin and print their result. The instructions would have the following format: `<operation>: <year> <month> <day> <name>`. There are 3 operations: 'S' (search), 'F' (find) and 'D' (delete). The store instruction would store the entry in the database and print "Stored" or "Already stored" if the entry was already in the database. The find instructions would print "Found" if the entry was in the database, otherwise it would print "Not found". The delete instructions would delete the entry from the database and print "Deleted" if it found the entry, otherwise it would print "Not found".

I couldn't simply use a linked list for my solution, because of time constraints. First I tried using a hash map ([pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/JDNS9qPw)). Than I tried using a binary search tree, but hashing the entry ([pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/jqimp3sy)). Neither of these attempts worked (they passed the simple tests but failed on the large test). Finally I just tried the "simplest" approach - binary tree that stores the whole entry. This attempt also passed the simple tests but failed on the large test... Now I'm totally stuck. Here's my current code:

```c
#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
    #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
    #define scanf scanf_s // Bit hacky ngl.
#endif

#include <stddef.h> // NULL
#include <stdio.h>  // scanf()/scanf_s(), puts()
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc(), free()
#include <string.h> // strcmp()

typedef struct {
    unsigned short year;
    unsigned char month, day;
    char *name;
} User;

typedef struct BinaryTreeNode {
    struct BinaryTreeNode *left, *right;
    User user;
} BinaryTree;

static inline BinaryTree *BinaryTree_alloc(User user) {
    BinaryTree *tree = (BinaryTree *) malloc(sizeof(BinaryTree));
    tree->left  = NULL;
    tree->right = NULL;
    tree->user  = user;
    return tree;
}

static inline void BinaryTree_dealloc(BinaryTree *tree) {
    if (tree) {
        BinaryTree_dealloc(tree->left);
        BinaryTree_dealloc(tree->right);
        free(tree);
    }
}

int BinaryTree_compare(BinaryTree *tree, User user) {
         if (tree->user.year  > user.year)  return  1;
    else if (tree->user.year  < user.year)  return -1;
    else if (tree->user.month > user.month) return  1;
    else if (tree->user.month < user.month) return -1;
    else if (tree->user.day   > user.day)   return  1;
    else if (tree->user.day   < user.day)   return -1;
    else return strcmp(tree->user.name, user.name);
}

BinaryTree *BinaryTree_store(BinaryTree *tree, User user) {
    if (tree) {
        switch (BinaryTree_compare(tree, user)) {
            case  1: tree->left  = BinaryTree_store(tree->left,  user); break;
            case -1: tree->right = BinaryTree_store(tree->right, user); break;
            default: puts("Already stored");
        }
        return tree;
    }
    puts("Stored");
    return BinaryTree_alloc(user);
}

BinaryTree *BinaryTree_find(BinaryTree *tree, User user) {
    if (tree)
        switch (BinaryTree_compare(tree, user)) {
            case  1: return BinaryTree_find(tree->left,  user);
            case -1: return BinaryTree_find(tree->right, user);
            default: puts("Found");
        }
    else puts("Not found");
    return tree;
}

static inline User BinaryTree_find_min_user(BinaryTree *tree) {
    while (tree->left) tree = tree->left;
    return tree->user;
}

BinaryTree *BinaryTree_delete(BinaryTree *tree, User user) {
    if (tree)
        switch (BinaryTree_compare(tree, user)) {
            case  1: tree->left  = BinaryTree_delete(tree->left,  user); break;
            case -1: tree->right = BinaryTree_delete(tree->right, user); break;
            default:
                if (!tree->left && !tree->right) {
                    free(tree->user.name);
                    free(tree);
                    tree = NULL;
                    puts("Deleted");
                }
                else if (!tree->left || !tree->right) {
                    BinaryTree *root = tree;
                    if (!tree->left)  tree = tree->left;
                    if (!tree->right) tree = tree->right;
                    free(root->user.name);
                    free(root);
                    puts("Deleted");
                }
                else {
                    User min_user = BinaryTree_find_min_user(tree->right);
                    tree->user  = min_user;
                    tree->right = BinaryTree_delete(tree->right, min_user);
                }
        }
    else puts("Not found");
    return tree;
}

int main() {
    char operation;
    User user;
    BinaryTree *tree = BinaryTree_alloc((User) { 0, 0, 0, NULL });
    while (5 == scanf(" %c : %hu %hhu %hhu %m[^\n]",
        &operation,
        &user.year,
        &user.month,
        &user.day,
        &user.name)) {
        switch (operation) {
            case 'S': BinaryTree_store (tree, user); break;
            case 'F': BinaryTree_find  (tree, user); break;
            case 'D': BinaryTree_delete(tree, user); break;
        }
    }
    BinaryTree_dealloc(tree);
}
```

Someone please help me :3

Comment: You've got a lot of code here and I can't see any tests that validate it. You may want to write *unit tests* that can validate individual functions before trying to run the whole thing end-to-end with the expectation of it to working perfectly.

Comment: Why does your `BinaryTree_find` function always return a pointer even when it found nothing? In C the convention is to return `NULL` on a miss. The only hint here as to finding or not finding is STDOUT output and that's not something the caller of this function can utilize.

Comment: One-line fix: your search should _only_ search on the key, _viz_ the date, if you want your entries to be one-to-one. This (when working) stores multiple data with different names on the same date, which is, I think, not what you want?

Comment: Two quick comments: `BinaryTree_compare()` every `else` is superfluous. Get rid of them. And, without "self-balancing", a BST fed with sorted data is nothing more than an expensive LL...

Comment: @Fe2O3 As such, the hash-map solution is probably the easiest. `fnv1a` is a good string hash, but again, calculate the hash based on the key alone.

Comment: @Neil Yes. `snprintf( buf, "%04d%02d%02d%s", yr, mo, dy, name );` The OP needs to add some preliminary validation, of course, but there's no reason the data cannot be converted to a single string and processed much more simply (including the benefits of using a hashtable for search/retrieval.)

Comment: What's the question? "failed on the large test" doesn't tell us anything.  What failed?  How? What is "large"?  How do we reproduce the issue?  You talk about operations but not how data gets into your database so what's the initial state?

Comment: The write-up says "S" is for search but your implementation says "S" for store.

Comment: It's odd you start with am empty node instead of just `tree = NULL`.

Comment: C doesn't guarantee tail call optimization so you are better off using iterative rather than recursive algorithms.

Comment: Your compare function is bit a odd.  Consider passing a pointer to the two users you want to compare instead of a tree pointer and a copy of a user (i.e. not a pointer).

Comment: `strcmp()` is not guaranteed to return -1, 0 and 1.  Either update `BinaryTree_compare` to ensure that your function does, or change how callers handle the return value (i.e. with an `if``-`else if`-`else` instead of a `switch)`.

Comment: Either user camel or snake case (what I prefer).  Both is confusing.

Comment: @SergeBallesta You are tired.  The `m` format string allocates it and store just copies the pointer to the allocated memory.  This feature is not supported on all platforms though.

Comment: @AllanWind: Thanks for the head up. Time to have a coffee... ;-)

Comment: Wait, is the _name_ part of the key, too, or just the _date_? Can you have different names on the same date? For that matter, can you have different _date_ and the same _name_?

Comment: You got a couple of answers below.  Make sure you accept the best one by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

1. (Scalability) I am not sure what the problem is but you mention failure on "large" tests so switch from passing the `User` to `User *` on your recursive functions will use less stack space.
2. (Not fixed) C doesn't guarantee tail call optimization so you should prefer iterative to recursive algorithms.  Recursive algorithms have a stack size that is bound by the input size.
3. (Style) If you handle the special case first then your normal case, which is often long, is less indented.  You expect base cases first in recursive functions.
4. (Defect) `BinaryTree_compare()` is odd as you are comparing two users so changed it to `User_compare()` and pass in two `User *` instead.  Callers assume that the function return `-1`, `0`, or `1` however that is not the case for `strcmp()` so ensure that it now does.  In the calls, I also switched the arguments as it makes more sense to me that -1 means `left` side of tree, and `+1` right side.
5. (Not fixed) Consider refactoring `BinaryTree_find()` and/or `BinaryTree_store()` to eliminate very similar code.
6. (Refactor) `BinaryTree_delete()`: This is perfectly fine:

```
                    if (!tree->left)  tree = tree->left;
                    if (!tree->right) tree = tree->right;
```

but I think it's clearer to use an `else` to express that we only change either the left or right branch.  I usually get rid of the negation and fond of the tertiary operator:

```
                    tree = tree->left ? tree->right : tree->left;
```

1. (Change) `main()` allocates an empty node but I think it makes more sense just staring with NULL.  `BinaryTree_store()` and `BinaryTree_delete()` returns the changed root nodes already.
2. Remove the `inline` keyboard as the compiler probably knows better than you anyways (if it even uses it).  I would probably eliminate `BinaryTree_find_min_user()` and just have that one-liner in `BinaryTree_delete()`.
3. (Not fixed) Choose either camel or snake case (my preference).  Not both.
4. (Not fixed) Add a lot more tests cases especially for store and delete.
5. (Not fixed) Consider using an `enum` for your operators, and add default case in `main()` to handle user asking for non-existing operation (even if that is ignoring it).

```
#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#define scanf scanf_s // Bit hacky ngl.
#endif

#include <stddef.h> // NULL
#include <stdio.h>  // scanf()/scanf_s(), puts()
#include <stdlib.h> // malloc(), free()
#include <string.h> // strcmp()

typedef struct {
    unsigned short year;
    unsigned char month, day;
    char *name;
} User;

typedef struct BinaryTreeNode {
    struct BinaryTreeNode *left, *right;
    User user;
} BinaryTree;

static BinaryTree *BinaryTree_alloc(const User *user) {
    BinaryTree *tree = malloc(sizeof *tree);
    tree->left  = NULL;
    tree->right = NULL;
    tree->user  = *user;
    return tree;
}

static void BinaryTree_dealloc(BinaryTree *tree) {
    if (!tree) return;
    BinaryTree_dealloc(tree->left);
    BinaryTree_dealloc(tree->right);
    free(tree);
}

int User_compare(const User *a, const User *b) {
    if (a->year > b->year)  return  1;
    else if (a->year  < b->year)  return -1;
    else if (a->month > b->month) return  1;
    else if (a->month < b->month) return -1;
    else if (a->day   > b->day)   return  1;
    else if (a->day   < b->day)   return -1;
    int rv = strcmp(a->name, b->name);
    return rv < 0 ? -1 : rv > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

BinaryTree *BinaryTree_store(BinaryTree *tree, const User *user) {
    if (!tree) {
        puts("Stored");
        return BinaryTree_alloc(user);
    }
    switch (User_compare(user, &tree->user)) {
        case -1: tree->left = BinaryTree_store(tree->left, user); break;
        case 1: tree->right = BinaryTree_store(tree->right, user); break;
        default: puts("Already stored");
    }
    return tree;
}

BinaryTree *BinaryTree_find(BinaryTree *tree, const User *user) {
    if (!tree) {
        puts("Not found");
        return NULL;
    }
    switch (User_compare(user, &tree->user)) {
        case -1: return BinaryTree_find(tree->left, user);
        case  1: return BinaryTree_find(tree->right, user);
        default: puts("Found");
    }
    return tree;
}

static User *BinaryTree_find_min_user(BinaryTree *tree) {
    for (; tree->left; tree = tree->left);
    return &tree->user;
}

BinaryTree *BinaryTree_delete(BinaryTree *tree, User *user) {
    if (!tree) {
        puts("Not found");
        return tree;
    }
    switch (User_compare(user, &tree->user)) {
        case -1: tree->right = BinaryTree_delete(tree->right, user); break;
        case  1: tree->left  = BinaryTree_delete(tree->left,  user); break;
        default:
            if (!tree->left && !tree->right) {
                free(tree->user.name);
                free(tree);
                tree = NULL;
                puts("Deleted");
            }
            else if (!tree->left || !tree->right) {
                BinaryTree *root = tree;
                tree = tree->left ? tree->right : tree->left;
                free(root->user.name);
                free(root);
                puts("Deleted");
            }
            else {
                User *min_user = BinaryTree_find_min_user(tree->right);
                tree->user  = *min_user;
                tree->right = BinaryTree_delete(tree->right, min_user);
            }
    }
    return tree;
}

int main(void) {
    char operation;
    User *user = &(User) {0};
    BinaryTree *tree = NULL;
    while (5 == scanf(" %c : %hu %hhu %hhu %m[^\n]",
            &operation,
            &user->year,
            &user->month,
            &user->day,
            &user->name)) {
        switch (operation) {
            case 'S': tree = BinaryTree_store (tree, user); break;
            case 'F': BinaryTree_find  (tree, user); break;
            case 'D': tree = BinaryTree_delete(tree, user); break;
        }
    }
    BinaryTree_dealloc(tree);
}
```

and example run:

```
$ cat input.txt
S : 2023 11 28 m
S : 2023 11 28 m
S : 2023 11 28 a
S : 2023 11 28 z
S : 2023 11 28 j
F : 2023 11 28 m
D : 2023 11 28 m
F : 2023 11 28 m
F : 2023 11 28 j
$ ./a.out < input.txt
Stored
Already stored
Stored
Stored
Stored
Found
Deleted
Not found
Found
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `strcmp` means that (at least on some platforms, like mine) the `switch` will behave wrongly when values different from 0, 1 or -1 are returned.

For example:

```
S: 1978 9 3 Victor
S: 2002 1 2 Foxtrot
D: 1978 9 3 Romeo     --> core dump [strcmp returns 'V'-'R' = 4]
```

This only happens for *some* combination of inputs, so this might be why the short tests pass, and the long one fails.

To improve performances (o-ranking remains the same), you could initialize an array of 12 * 31 trees, where the trees only contain the year and the user name. Since search on the array is o(1) - you jump straight to the [31*month+day]-th tree - and compare functions needn't worry with day and month, this might help overcome time constraints.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I would consider re-visiting the hash-map, as it is probably going to be the most performent and simplest across a greater range of problem sizes. A tree is easy to get the worst-case, in which case, it is much like a linked-list, (unless it has some more complicated re-balancing, *eg* [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).)

*fnv1a* is a good choice for a byte-oriented data, but two real design problems prevent you from realizing the hash-map, (since all data is part of the key, I'd say it's a hash-set.)

1. There are some equivalents, but in general, one **must** have the functions like `hash hashcode(key)`, `boolean equals(entry, entry)`, (`key` is equivalent `entry` in this set); if two entries are `equals` they have the same `hashcode`.
2. With your current scheme, you can only have one collision before it overwrites the data. I've fixed this with simple [linear probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing). There are more complex algorithms, (*Knuth AoCP3 6.4 Hashing*), but as long as you keep the load-factor under 0.6, it's doubtful it would make a difference.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
//#include "orcish.h" debug

struct User {
    union {
        struct { uint16_t year; uint8_t month, day; };
        uint32_t date;
    };
    uint32_t hash; /* Cache; not really needed, but wasted alignment anyway. */
    char *name; /* "valid" will be non-null -- no sense duplicating. */
};

#define FNV1A_OFFSET 2166136261 /*0xCBF29CE484222325*/
#define FNV1A_PRIME  16777619 /*0x00000100000001B3*/
/* Prime number less than 10_000_000 / 16, for added cache performance? */
#define HASHMAP_SIZE 624997 /*8*/
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 63
#define STRX(x) #x
#define STR(x) STRX(x) /* For debugging. */

struct Hashset { struct User bucket[HASHMAP_SIZE]; };

/** Hash `user`. I think 64-bit: 1.8e19 is overkill if you went to wrap it in a
 35MB table. 32-bit: 4.3e9 is more than enough? */
static uint32_t fnv1a_hash_user(const struct User *const user) {
    uint32_t hash = FNV1A_OFFSET;
    /* FNV1a is an octect-by-octect algorithm; doesn't really matter. */
    hash = (hash ^ user->date) * FNV1A_PRIME;
    for(const unsigned char *a = (const unsigned char *)user->name;
        *a != '\0'; a++) hash = (hash ^ *a) * FNV1A_PRIME;
    return hash;
}

/** Compares **valid** Users. */
static bool user_is_equal(const struct User *const restrict u1,
    const struct User *const restrict u2) {
    return u1->date == u2->date && !strcmp(u1->name, u2->name);
}

/** Returns whether `set` has `probe`; `probe` will be hashed and cached.
 `no` is the pointer to a bucket match or the empty bucket next in line. */
static bool linear_probing(struct Hashset *const set,
    struct User *const probe, uint32_t *no) {
    probe->hash = fnv1a_hash_user(probe);
    uint32_t bucket_no = probe->hash;
    bool found;
    for( ; ; bucket_no++) {
        bucket_no %= HASHMAP_SIZE;
        const struct User *const bucket = set->bucket + bucket_no;
        if(!bucket->name) { found = false; break; }
        if(bucket->hash != probe->hash) continue;
        if(user_is_equal(bucket, probe)) { found = true; break; }
    }
    *no = bucket_no;
    return found;
}

/** Deletes `rem` from `set`, which must be a valid entry. */
static void delete_index(struct Hashset *const set, uint32_t rem) {
    for( ; ; ) {
        /* We want to find `replace`, the farthest entry in the cluster that
         can be switched with `rem`. We probe linearly, updating `replace`
         when a new cluster entry is further. (Not tested thoroughly!) */
        uint32_t replace = rem, probe = replace;
        for( ; ; ) {
            probe = (probe + 1) % HASHMAP_SIZE;
            const struct User *const u = set->bucket + probe;
            if(!u->name) break; /* End of cluster. */
            uint32_t probe0 = u->hash % HASHMAP_SIZE;
            /* What `probe` would be if it were closed, is in the space between
             `rem` and `probe`, it is not suited for replacement. */
            if(rem < probe0 ^ probe0 <= probe ^ probe < rem) replace = probe;
        }
        /* There's no more to replace. */
        if(rem == replace) break;
        free(set->bucket[rem].name), set->bucket[rem].name = 0;
        set->bucket[rem] = set->bucket[replace], set->bucket[replace].name = 0;
        rem = replace;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int success = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    struct Hashset *set = malloc(sizeof *set);
    if(!set) goto catch;
    /* Null is not guaranteed to be 0. */
    for(size_t i = 0; i < HASHMAP_SIZE; i++) set->bucket[i].name = 0;

    char operation;
    struct User probe;
    uint32_t bucket;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];

    while (5 == scanf(" %c : %"SCNu16" %"SCNu8" %"SCNu8
        " %"STR(MAX_NAME_LEN)"s[^\n]",
        &operation, &probe.year, &probe.month, &probe.day, name)) {
        int nl = getchar();
        if(nl != '\n') { fprintf(stderr, "Name too long.\n"); goto catch; }
        /*fprintf(stderr, "Got: %c: %"PRIu16"-%"PRIu8"-%"PRIu8" \"%s\"\n",
            operation, probe.year, probe.month, probe.day, name);*/
        probe.name = name; /* Just temporary so we can calculate the hash. */
        bool found = linear_probing(set, &probe, &bucket);
        switch (operation) {
        case 'S': /* store */
            if(found) {
                puts("Already stored");
            } else {
                /* Store a more permanent copy of `name`. */
                size_t name_size = strlen(name) + 1;
                if(!(probe.name = malloc(name_size))) goto catch;
                memcpy(probe.name, name, name_size);
                set->bucket[bucket] = probe;
                puts("Stored");
            }
            break;
        case 'F': /* find */
            puts(found ? "Found" : "Not found");
            break;
        case 'D':
            if (found) {
                delete_index(set, bucket);
                puts("Deleted");
            } else {
                puts("Not found");
            }
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "'%c' is not S, F, D.\n", operation);
            goto catch;
        }
    }
    if(!feof(stdin)) { fprintf(stderr, "Garbage input.\n"); goto catch; }
    goto finally;
catch:
    if(errno) perror("hashset");
    success = EXIT_FAILURE;
finally:
    for (size_t idx = 0; HASHMAP_SIZE > idx; idx++)
        if (set->bucket[idx].name)
            free(set->bucket[idx].name), set->bucket[idx].name = 0;
    free(set);
    return success;
}
```

This assumes the table is never full. The earlier code was mutating the entry in the `fnv1a_hash_user`; `const` ensures one can't do that. I've fixed memory leaks; `%m` is not supported on my compiler. `struct User` now includes a `union date`, which is easier to work with than the components.